# How to use HTML links in ASP.Net Core MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently trying to make a website in ASP.NET Core MVC. In my layout page, I'm making a navigation bar to access all of the actions that can be reached through my controllers. I am however unable to create useful links.

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="homepage">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index">Index</a></li>
</ul>
```

My problem with this is that I still need the controller before the links and if I put the controller in front of the action like this

```
<ul>

        <li><a href="home/homepage">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="home/index">What We've Done</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click on one link and then the other, the link will end up being "myurl/home/home/page".

How can I create the link to only link to the exact page I want to?

Comment: have you tried using Razor instead of html?

Comment: Please, don't use MVC6 tags anymore. It's for a future version of ASP.NET MVC based on the old webstack (MVC5). ASP.NET Core is a complete new and incompatible, portable version based on .NET Core.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use the anchor tag helper to build the markup for the link

```
<a asp-action="index" asp-controller="home">Home</a>
```

This will generate the correct relative path to the index action as the href property value of the anchor tag.